# Why does color bars change the color in cycle drawing? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

For each time, when the bars are drawing, they change their color random. Why?
What is reason of it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
fig = plt.figure()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax4.set_xlim(-10,80)
ax4.set_ylim(0,30)

def view(ylist):

    xmin = 0
    xmax = 70.0
    dx = 10
    xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)

    ax4.bar(xlist, ylist, dx)
    plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.draw()

ylist = [0 for p in range(8)]
for i in range(10):
    view(ylist)
    ylist[0] +=1
    ylist[3] +=2

plt.close()
```

While  running the code - bars are changing colors in cycle. Why?
The question is - what the matter?

Comment: hm... why put me "-" without any words... Is it really stupid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are plotting 10 different bars, all on the same axes. Your bars are being plotted at the same x coordinate and so are plotted on top of each other. This still means that your other bars are still there and so matplotlib cycles the colours of the "new" bars being plotted.

There are 2 things you can do. Firstly you can call `plt.cla()` which clears the current axes. This however will reset you y axis limits (which makes it look like nothing much is happening). This means you will have to set the y axis limits using `ax4.set_ylim(0,20)`.

Secondly, you can specify what colour you want the bars to be, in `ax4.bar()` (though this is still plotting over the old bars).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab

fig = plt.figure()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax4.set_xlim(-10,80)
ax4.set_ylim(0,30)

def view(ylist):

    xmin = 0
    xmax = 70.0
    dx = 10
    xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)

    plt.cla()
    ax4.set_ylim(0,20)
    ax4.bar(xlist, ylist, dx)  # can add color="blue" if you don't want to use plt.cla()
    plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.draw()

ylist = [0 for p in range(8)]
for i in range(10):
    view(ylist)
    ylist[0] +=1
    ylist[3] +=2

plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The last question is:
Does the  `plt.cla()` clear the memory?